# NextJS getting param from request.body if it doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following code in my nextJS api:

```
export default async function handler(request, response) {
    if (request.method === "POST") {

        const type = request.body.type ?? 'body type'
        const id = request.body.id ?? 34

        console.log(type, id)

        if(!type || !id ) {
            // Not acceptable.  You are missing a required parameter.
            return response.status(406).end()
        }

        const data = await getObjects(type, id)
        return response.status(200).json(data);

    } else {
        return response.status(405).end();
    }
}
```

However, if the API doesnt get one of the parameters (type or id) then it causes an XML error.

```
XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3002/api/list-objects
[HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable 262ms]

[Fast Refresh] rebuilding hot-dev-client.js:159:24
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:3002/api/list-objects
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

If the params dont have a value it fails in this same way.  How can I ensure it fail gracefully if the values are not present? I would have thought the `??` operator would take care of that but its not fixing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fetch` on the client, it doesn’t handle error status codes as errors, so it’s probably trying to parse your error (empty) content.

Before parsing the result, you can check the returned status code and throw an error if it isn’t 200:

```
fetch('/your/api', {method: 'POST'})
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error('API returned an error')
    }
    // Do your parsing here. E.g. for JSON:
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```